# Método para comparar un valor ingresado con los valores de un arreglo de objetos

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Operación extends ManejarArchivo
{
   static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   public  static ArrayList<Dato> Menores = new ArrayList();
   public static void Menorque(){
    System.out.println("Ingrese el valor a comparar");
    double Valor = scan.nextDouble();
    for(int i = 0; i < Datos.length; i++ ){
           if(Dato.getHumedad() < Valor){
             Menores.add(Datos1);  
           }
    }
    System.out.println(Menores);
   }
}
```

Tengo este código lo que intento es pedirle un dato al usuario y ese dato compararlo con un dato específico de un arreglo de objetos pero no he podido lograrlo sería de mucha ayuda que me asesoren con esto soy novato en Java y no se exactamente de qué forma podría lograr eso.

La siguiente clase es donde se encuentra el arreglo y se crean los objetos, y esos objetos se agregan al arreglo

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;

public class ManejarArchivo {
  public static ArrayList<Dato> Datos = new ArrayList();
  public static String Partes[];
  public static void LeerArchivo(String URL/*Direccion URL*/,String Fichero/*Direccion del fichero en el computador*/) throws Exception {
   URL ficheroUrl = new URL(URL);//Se declara la Direccion URL de tipo URL
   try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ficheroUrl.openStream()))) {
    String linea;
    String[] parts;
        while ((linea = in.readLine()) != null){
        parts = linea.split("\\{");
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Fichero));
        FileWriter w = new FileWriter(Fichero);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(w);
        PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(bw);
        for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
            wr.write(parts[i]);
            bw.newLine();
        }//escribimos en el archivo
        wr.close();
        bw.close();
    }
   } catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.out.println("link no encontrado  intenta de nuevo, el error fue este: " +e);
        }
  }
  public static void CrearObjeto(String Fichero){
     try(BufferedReader Bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Fichero))){
        String cadena = "";
        FileReader f = new FileReader(Fichero);
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
        int ContadorLineas = 1;
        while((cadena = b.readLine())!=null) {
            ContadorLineas++;
            if(ContadorLineas >= 5){
             Partes = cadena.split(",");             
             String Fecha = Partes[0];
             String ID = Partes[1];
             String Humedad = Partes[2];
             String F[] = Fecha.split(":");
             String FechaFinal = F[1]+F[2]+F[3];
             String ID2[] = ID.split(":");
             String ID3 = ID2[1];
             int IDFINAL = Integer.parseInt(ID3);
             String Humedad1[] = Humedad.split(":");
             String Humedad2 = Humedad1[1];
             int Caracteres = Humedad2.length();             
             String Humedad3 = Humedad2.substring(1,Caracteres-1);
             double HumedadFinal = Double.parseDouble(Humedad3);
             Dato Datos1 = new Dato(FechaFinal,IDFINAL,HumedadFinal);
             Datos.add(Datos1);
             }
        }                
        b.close();
    }catch(Exception E){
        System.out.println("Se produjo un error, por favor intente de nuevo");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Para comparar lo mejor es implementar la interfaz Comparable.